"sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked" on a brand-new database file
This code which has been working for years has now suddenly started returning the above error even for a newly created database.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
    dbfile = os.path.expanduser(dbfile)
    import sqlite3 as sqlite

    dbsetup = not os.path.isfile(dbfile)
    conn = sqlite.connect(dbfile)
    c = conn.cursor()
    if dbsetup:
        c.execute("create table counters (module text, counter int)")
    c.execute("select counter from counters where module = '%s'" % name)
    r = c.fetchone()




y=global_counter('x','~/test.db')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/data/jwst/scheduling/tools/com/spss_sys_util.py", line 1227, in global_counter
c.execute("create table counters (module text, counter int)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked



Any hints as to what might be going on?

Hi!  I don't mean to discourage you, but this question is pretty hard to answer mostly because  there isn't a "minimal reproducible example" that a potential answerer (like me) can run to reproduce your problem on my machine. Often times bugs don't come from the code snippet that we think is most relevant.

But maybe these troubleshooting steps would help? https://docs.pyrogram.org/faq/sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked

The is no other possible connection to the database to kill.  This is happening for a brand-new, just create by me, database.

Problem solved.  It was a disk space issue.
